# centered element in background doesn't match centered element in foreground

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application where I want to create a windowBackground with a centered element and a layout also with a centered element. I want these elements to be in the exact same position, with the layout overlapping the background. The problem I'm having is that the layout and the background seem to be calculating center differently (see image). Why is this happening, and what can I do to line the elements up?

This is what I see right now. The red box is created by the background and the green box is created by the foreground. Screenshot was created with a Nexus 5X API 26 emulator.
[image: centered element mismatch example]

Foreground layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:background="@color/foreground_box"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Background Drawable (applied via `android:windowBackground` in my theme)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/background_box" />
            <size android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

For clarity, my colors file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    ...
    <color name="background">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="background_box">#AAFF0000</color>
    <color name="foreground_box">#AA00FF00</color>
</resources>
```

Full source for this sample project is available at https://github.com/HofmaDresu/AndroidCenteredTest

Comment: background_box color is green ?

Comment: It seems like you have added this extra line 
 <item android:drawable="@color/background" />
I am checking it.

Comment: background_box color is red

Comment: The first <item> is to set an overall background color (white in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `windowBackground` includes both the heights **1) statusBar and 2) actionBar**

Modify below line in your background.xml

```
<item android:gravity="center" android:top="80dp"> // 56 actionBarSize + 24 statusBarHeight
```

You may need to manage this programatically as statusBarHeight and actionBarSize varies based on device API/resolution.

Here is the result. For testing, have resized background size bit bigger so that overlapping between views and background become visible.

[image]

Comment: Note that neither the status bar height nor the action bar height are consistent across devices/configurations, and so hardcoding `80dp` may work well on many devices but will not on others.

Comment: @BenP. Agreed !! thats what I mentioned in answer post to manage the heights pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the extra space taken up by the `ActionBar` in the foreground.

To fix this, you can add a margin to your `View` in the foreground layout as:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: That pushes the boxes apart, forcing the green 'foreground' box further down on the page. The issue occurs even if I adjust my theme to remove the action bar, though the green foreground box is above the red background box in that case

Comment: @HofmaDresu My bad. I've edited the answer to correct it. Basically since there is an `ActionBar` on top, we're creating an equal margin on the bottom so that the center is not disturbed.

Comment: This is still a problem even if I remove the action bar. My real-life situation doesn't have one

Comment: I also tested this code with marginBottom and the boxes don't line up

Answer (score 0):

After test it in AS, I can say you that the right code for you background_drawable is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />

    <item android:gravity="center" android:bottom="48dp">
    <shape
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/background_box" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

using **android:top**, the red square go more down than center. Need to use **android:bottom** instead to center background. By my tests results that 48dp is the right value.